# Asp.net MVC jquery-ajax don't render html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery ajax with MVC I can get it to post back to the action I want and it returns the ViewData objects with updated Data but never renders the HTML. I have a View which contains some MVC User Controls and I want them to update on a timer.

Here is my View Markup

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/PageWithSummaryViewAndTabs.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="FullCaseTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="FullCaseContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setInterval(test, 5000);
function test() {
    jQuery.get("/PatientCase/RefreshEPRF", function(response) { });
}
</script>

<div id="loadingDiv" style="display:none">Updating</div>

   <input id="refreshPatientCaseIndexButton" type="submit" visible="true" title="refresh" value="Refresh" />
    <h2>Full Case</h2>
    <div id="EPRFContent"> 
        <%Html.RenderPartial(@"~/Views/PatientCase/SectionEPRF.ascx"); %>
        <%Html.RenderPartial(@"~/Views/PatientCase/SectionDrugs.ascx"); %>
    </div>
    <div id="ImageContent"> 
        <%Html.RenderPartial(@"~/Views/PatientCase/SectionImagery.ascx"); %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

On postback i call a Action Called RefreshEPRF which loads just the required user controls again

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%Html.RenderPartial(@"~/Views/PatientCase/SectionEPRF.ascx"); %>
<%Html.RenderPartial(@"~/Views/PatientCase/SectionDrugs.ascx"); %>
```

And finaly the marpup in the control

```
<table id="detailstable">
    <tr><td id="detailslablecolumn">Patient Name : </td><td>
    <%
    foreach (var item in (List<STS_Lite.Models.PatinetCase.EPRFItem>)ViewData["EPRF"])
    {
        if (item.datumItemId == 46)
        {
            if (item.Stroke)
            {
            %>
                <img src="/PatientCaseIndex/InkImageData/GetInkImage/<%=ViewData["PatientCaseId"]%>/<%=ViewData["TemplateInstanceId"]%>/<%=item.TemplateItemId %>" />
            <%
            }
            else
            {%>
                <%=item.Value.ToString()%>
            <%} 
            break;
        }
    } 
%></td></tr><table>
```

When I step through this code the ViewData in the user control has the new updated values but the page comes back with no new values. I have tried the jQuery.get and ajax but with no luck.
Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your response... try doing this :

```
    jQuery.get("/PatientCase/RefreshEPRF", function(response) { 
        $("#EPRFContent").html(response) });
```

The response parameter should contain your view, and doing this simply put its content into your div.

your action Called RefreshEPRF should however return a partial view